# Low Earth Orbit period calculation issues

Tags: orbit, low-earth-orbit

So [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) says that the orbit period at 2000km (upper limit of LEO) is about 127 minutes, but when I calculate...

$$T=\sqrt{\frac{4 \pi^2r^3}{\mu}}=\sqrt{\frac{4 \pi^2(2000 \text{ km})^3}{398600 \text{ km}^3/\text{s}^2}}=890 \text{ s}$$

I get 14.8 minutes. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Here's the notation we use.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: You got the answer, now here's a [shortcut](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=sqrt%28%282000+km+%2B+6378.1+km%29^3*4*pi^2%2F%28%286.673%C3%9710^%E2%88%9211+N*%28m%2Fkg%29^2%29+*+5.97219%C3%9710^24+kg%29%29). Just replace the _2000 km_ with any altitude above Earth to get its orbital period. If you want in minutes, just add _[in minutes](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=sqrt%28%282000+km+%2B+6378.1+km%29^3*4*pi^2%2F%28%286.673%C3%9710^%E2%88%9211+N*%28m%2Fkg%29^2%29+*+5.97219%C3%9710^24+kg%29%29+in+minutes)_ to the end of the formula. Or  any other time unit you want that Google recognizes. ;)

Answer (score 12):

You're using the orbit's *altitude* as the orbital radius. Add the radius of Earth to the orbit altitude to get the actual radius.

Note that an Earth orbit at 2000km radius would be subject to significant lithospheric drag.

Comment: *lithospheric drag* ... lol!

Comment: quite a sleeper here! maybe we need a Wiki to start curating these.